# Stop mod_rewrite returning REQUEST_URI when (.*) is empty

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mocks/site/(.*)$ http://thelivewebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That is my htaccess file's contents.

The htaccess file is in the root directory of the hosting account and I just want to redirect the directory `mocks/site/` to the new domain (with or without any extra directories).

eg: if someone goes to `http://mywebsite.com/mocks/site` then it needs to redirect to `http://thelivewebsite.com`. If they go to `http://mywebsite.com/mocks/site/another/directory` then it needs to redirect to `http://thelivewebsite.com/another/directory`. I hope that makes sense.

So the problem I have is that the htaccess code above seems to work pretty well when there is something after `mocks/site/` however when there isn't something after that then the `$1` in the redirect seems to reference the whole REQUEST_URI (eg: `mocks/site/` rather than nothing - as there is nothing after it).

I don't know how to stop this. I thought about using a RewriteCond, but I'm not sure what to use there. I can't find anything that helps me to determine if there is anything after `mocks/site/` or not.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's **very strange** behaviour -- never seen anything like that. Therefore I think it could be something else (**another rule somewhere** -- on old or even new site). I recommend enabling rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check the rewrite log (that's **if you can** edit Apache's config file / virtual host definition).

In any case, **try this combination**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^mocks/site/$ http://thelivewebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mocks/site/(.+)$ http://thelivewebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will do matching/redirecting in 2 steps: first rule is for exact directory match (so no `$1` involved at all) and 2nd will work if there is at least 1 character after the `/mocks/site/`.

**Alternatively** (Apache docs even recommending this one) use `Redirect` directive (no need for mod_rewrite at all [for such simple redirects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html)):

```
Redirect 301 /mocks/site/ http://thelivewebsite.com/
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you, your first suggestion helped. :) Where it redirects first if there's nothing after. The redirect directive didn't seem to do anything, so I was probably doing it wrong, but its ok the first one works fine.